# How to call AS3 code from a web page inside an Adobe AIR application?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air

We have an Adobe AIR application that sometimes loads a web page. On one of these web pages there is a hyperlink. When the hyperlink is clicked I want an AS3 function to be called. I know how to call a JavaScript function when the hyperlink is clicked, but within the JavaScript function how do I call my AS3 function?

In all the examples I can find the Flash is a SWF on the webpage and is thus inside a DOM element. So in the code examples they call the AS3 function on a DOM element like so:

```
function sendTextToAS3() {
    var Txt = document.getElementById('htmlText').value;
    var flash = document.getElementById("as3_js");
    flash.sendTextFromJS(Txt);
    document.getElementById('htmlText').value = "";
}
```

But in my case the Flash is not a SWF inside a DOM element, instead the Flash is the whole Adobe Air app and there is no DOM element with a SWF. So what do I call my AS3 function on if I can't do it via a DOM element?

Comment: Are you using `HTMLLoader` or `StageWebView` to load a web page in your AIR app?

Comment: If you are using stagewebview then take a look at https://code.google.com/archive/p/stagewebviewbridge/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `mx:HTML` component to display your html page. Then you can call an as3 function from javascript using the following method:

1. Inside the html page, define the callback function:

   ```
   var linkClicked = function () {}
   ```
2. Inside the as3 code, define the callback function:

   ```
   function linkClicked():void {
       // Your logic here
   }
   ```
3. Inside the as3 code, override the definition of the callback function:

   ```
   // var html:HTML = new HTML();
   // load page ...
   // when the page is loaded
   html.domWindow.linkClicked = linkClicked;
   ```

For simplicity, the javascript `linkClicked` function is defined on the window object.

Now, the as3 code is executed every time you call `linkClicked` from javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the **ExternalInterface API**. See examples from the docs at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: `ExternalInterface` isn't what Ryan needs. This is exactly the example he gave that doesn't work, since he doesn't have a SWF embedded in an HTML page, he has an HTML page loaded into an AIR app.